# Android wear action remotely activates a service in handheld

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-notification

This seems like a simple thing to do, but there's very little documentation on this.

I want to send a demand to an android wear device like so when the user enters a specific activity:

[image]

then if the user is looking at his or her watch and presses the demand button, it does the same thing as pressing an identical button in the handheld app.

How can I accomplish this?

Specifically:

```
if (userPressedDemandButton) {
    if (!service.isRunning)
        service.start();
    else
        service.stop();
}
```

I know how to get a demand button to show up on a wear device like so, but I don't know how to send a message back to the handheld when the user presses the demand button.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access handheld device directly from wearable notification.
You should setup notification action handler, use [MessageAPI](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/messages.html) in it to send some action to handled and there do everything you want.